# How can I disable SSL verification with Reviewboards Python API?

Tags: python, ssl, review-board

In order to access a Reviewboard server I need to disable the SSL verification, however, I can't seem to do this from Reviewboard's Python API.

I've added a 'DISABLE_SSL_VERFICATION = True' line to ~/.reviewboardrc. The rbt commands themselves find this file ok, but scripts using the Python API don't seem to know it exists.

I'm seeing this behavior on both Ubuntu and a Cygwin install under Windows.

Is there something I'm missing with setting my Reviewboard configuration? Is there another way to disable SSL verification with the Python API?

Comment: Have a look here:

https://reviews.reviewboard.org/r/7275/

Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, that update gets me to the point that I can use the rbt command line tools properly, but the python API can't seem to find the config file (and, obviously, I can't add the command line flags to the python function calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to disable ssl verification globally, but there is a way to disable it when creating the RBClient that then carries through to any operations performed using that client.

Originally I was creating my client as below:

```
client = RBClient('server_url')
```

To disable ssl verification I added a verify_ssl argument and set it to false:

```
client = RBClient('server_url', verify_ssl=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option —disable-ssl-verification for all rbt commands.

For example to post to Review board using retools use the command below.

```
rbt post —disable-ssl-verification
```

The exact reason why this is required is because of the Python Library. If you are using a Python Library version greater than 2.7.9 you will need this additional option.